# Prove that the sequence $\{q_n\}_{n \geq 1}$ diverges to $\infty.$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

> Let $\{x_n \}_{n \geq 1}$ be a sequence of rational numbers converging to $\pi.$ Let for all $n \geq 1,$ $x_n = \frac {p_n} {q_n},$ where $p_n,q_n \in \Bbb Z$ with $\text {gcd}\ (p_n,q_n) = 1.$ Prove that the sequence $\{q_n \}_{n \geq 1}$ diverges to $\infty.$

How do I prove that? Any help will be highly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The $\gcd$ condition is not required.

Comment: Oh! I see. Can you please provide the way to approach @Yves Daoust sir?

Comment: @Yves Daoust sir can you please be more explicit? What's the lower bound of such approximation?

Comment: When you say "diverges to $\infty$" do you mean the sequence is unbounded, or do you mean that $q_n \to +\infty$? The former is what I think you mean but I want to make sure

Comment: Yeah you are right @perpetuallyconfused.

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1518349/42969.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose that $\{q_n\}$ is bounded, and suppose without loss of generality that $q_n > 0$. Since $q_n \in \mathbb{Z}$ is bounded, define $q = \text{lcm}\{q_n$}. Then we know that there exists $z \in \mathbb{Z}$ such that the following holds:

\begin{equation}
\frac{z}{q} < \pi < \frac{z+1}{q}.
\end{equation}

Then any $\frac{p_n}{q_n}$ can be written in the form $\frac{z'}{q}$, so cannot improve on the bounds in the above inequality. So we have that $\frac{p_n}{q_n}$ is bounded away from $\pi$.

Comment: So if we take $\varepsilon = \min \left \{\left ( \pi - \dfrac {z} {q} \right ) , \left ( \dfrac {z+1} {q} - \pi \right ) \right \}$ then we have $$\{x_n\ |\ n \in \Bbb N \} \cap B \left (\pi, \dfrac {\varepsilon} {2} \right ) = \varnothing.$$ Am I right? But this contradicts the fact that $x_n \to \pi$ as $n \to \infty.$

Comment: That looks correct to me

Comment: Elegant proof. +1 Many many thanks for your help.

Comment: No problem! I would recommend looking at some of the similar questions that are linked in the comment by @MartinR and on the side, since they'll help with similar questions like proving that the limit is irrational

Answer (score 0):

If the sequence $\{q_{n}\}$ is bounded then clearly $\{p_{n}\}$ must also be bounded as otherwise $\{x_{n}\}$ does not converge. Then $\{x_{n}\}$ must be bounded, and most importantly, finite. Since $\pi$ is irrational, the closest we can get to $\pi$ is obtained by taking the $x_{k}$ (which exists in $\{x_{n}\})$ such that $\inf\{|{x_{n}}-\pi|\}$ is satisfied by $n=k$. Since $x_{k} \neq \pi$, we see we cannot get arbitarily close to $\pi$ using a finite set of fractions. Take $\epsilon < \inf\{|{x_{n}}-\pi|\}$ and we see that $\{x_{n}\}$ does not converge to $\pi$, a contradiction.