# An interval of length exceeding $\sqrt n$ contains an integer coprime to $n$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

**True or false?** -

Let $n$ be a positive integer.  If $a$ and $b$ are integers with $b-a>\sqrt n\thinspace$, then there exists an integer $x$ coprime to $n$ in the interval $a\le x\le b$.

**Comments**.

- We may assume that $kn\le a<b<(k+1)n$ for some $k$, for if not then there is some $x=mn\pm1$ in the required range.
- And then the problem only depends on residues modulo $n$, so we may assume $0\le a<b\le n$.
- The conclusion need not be true if $a,b$ are not integers.  Trivial example: $n=2$, $a=1.1$, $b=2.9$.  Less trivial example: $n=30$, $a=1.1$, $b=6.9$.
- (Not 100% sure about this.)  If the statement is true for $n$ and $p\mid n$, then the statement is true for $pn$.  So if there is a counterexample, there must be a counterexample with squarefree $n$.

The problem was inspired by an attempted approach to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4618900/can-rationals-be-approximated-by-increasingly-large-denominator-rationals).

Comment: In your last bullet, do you mean "then the statement is true for $\frac pn$"?

Comment: @aschepler No.  If $p\mid n$ then (usually) $\frac pn$ would not be an integer and so the statement would not make sense anyway.

Comment: And there I actually meant $\frac np$.

Comment: @aschepler But still no, I meant $pn$.

Answer (score 2):

**Note:** This is an incomplete answer.

First, since you say you're not 100% sure, let's note that your last statement is true. Suppose the claim is true for $n$, and $p$ is a prime dividing $n$.  Then, consider an interval of length $> \sqrt{pn}.$ Certainly this interval has length $> \sqrt{n}$, hence contains an integer $m$ coprime to $n$ by assumption. Since $p|n,$ $m$ cannot be a multiple of $p$, hence $m$ is coprime to $pn$ as well. So, as you remark, we can restrict ourselves to considering only squarefree $n$.

Let's also look at the second bulletpoint. We can only assume $0 \leq a < b  \leq n$ (or in fact $0 \leq a < b < n$) if an interval of length $> \sqrt{n}$ can fit in $[0, n-1].$ In other words, we should have $n -1 > \sqrt{n}$, and thus $n \geq 3$. We can, however, just check that the claim is true for $n =2$ (any interval of length greater than $\sqrt{2}$ must have length at least $2,$ hence contains an odd number). Therefore, we can go ahead with this assumption (keeping in mind that $n \geq 3$ for the rest of the problem).

Now, we follow the argument given in the first answer here: [Count Integers Not Greater Than $a$ Coprime To $b$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3158012/count-integers-not-greater-than-a-coprime-to-b/3158036#3158036)

Given an interval $[a, b]$ of length $> \sqrt{n}$, the number of integers in this interval coprime to $n$ is given by
$$\sum_{m=a}^{b} \sum_{d|(m, n)} \mu(d) = \sum_{d|n}\mu(d)\sum_{a \leq m \leq b \\ d|m} 1.$$

Note that $\sum_{a \leq m \leq b \\ d|m} 1$ counts the number of integers divisible by $d$ in $[a, b]$. This is $\lfloor \frac{b-a}{d} \rfloor$ if $d \nmid a,$ and $\lfloor \frac{b-a}{d} \rfloor +1$ if $d \nmid a.$ The $+1$ terms contribute a total of $\sum_{d|n}\mu(d) = 0$, so we can ignore them.

Therefore, we are interested in estimating
$$\sum_{d|n}\mu(d)\lfloor \frac{b-a}{d} \rfloor = (b-a)\sum_{d|n}\frac{\mu(d)}{d} -\sum_{d|n} \mu(d)\left\{\frac{b-a}{d} \right\}.$$ Let $R = \sum_{d|n} \mu(d)\left\{\frac{b-a}{d} \right\}.$

We have
\begin{align}
(b-a)\sum_{d|n}\frac{\mu(d)}{d} -\sum_{d|n} \mu(d)\left\{\frac{b-a}{d} \right\} &= (b-a)\frac{\phi(n)}{n} - R\\
&> \sqrt{n} \cdot \frac{\phi(n)}{n} - R\\
&= \frac{\phi(n)}{\sqrt{n}} - R.
\end{align}
If we can show that $\frac{\phi(n)}{\sqrt{n}} - R \geq 1,$ we are done. In other words, we need to show that
$$\sum_{d|n} \mu(d)\left\{\frac{b-a}{d} \right\} \leq \frac{\phi(n) - \sqrt{n}}{\sqrt{n}}.$$ At this point, I don't know how to continue.

Comment: Thanks for those thoughts.  Unfortunately I rather fear that the inequality at the end is going to be just as hard as the original problem.  With regard to your second paragraph, the case where an inteval of length $\sqrt n$ does not fit in $[0,n-1]$ is covered by the "if not..." in my first bullet point, I believe.