# Proof that Thomae’s function is Riemann integrable

Tags: real-analysis, integration, proof-explanation

Let $h(x)= 0$ if $x$ is irrational and $1/q$ if $x=p/q$ where $p,q$ are natural numbers such that $gcd(p,q)=1$.

Show that the function is Riemann integrable.

The first part of the proof says: Let $\epsilon>0$ let $N\in \mathbb{N}$ such that $\frac{1}{N}<\frac{\epsilon}{2}$, then the number of $x's$  such that $h(x)>\frac{1}{N}$ are at most $N^2$.

**Then for any partition $P$ of $[0,1]$ there are at most $2N$ intervals containing some $x$ such that $h(x)>\frac{1}{N}$.**

My question is, how do you prove the statement in bold? and what's the intuition for it?
Lastly, when would I use such a method to show a function is integrable?

Comment: The worst case, when it's exactly $2N$, is when the partitions go from $0$ to $1/(2N)$, from $1/(2N)$ to $1/N$, from $1/N$ to $3/(2N)$, etc.

Comment: This has been addressed many times on this site.  See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1427790/148510) for an answer to your specific question and the follow-up with slight notational differences.