# How can I decide whether this function is integrable?

Tags: real-analysis, integration, definite-integrals, rational-numbers

A function $f$ is defined on $[0,1]$ such that for every

1. irrational number in $[0,1]$, $f(x)=1$ and
2. rational number in $[0,1]$, $f(x) = \dfrac{a-2}{a}$, where $a$ is the smallest natural number for which $ax$ is an integer.

Does $\int_0^1 f(x)dx$ exist? If yes, what's the value?

I have a hunch that it is not integrable, but somehow unable to proceed.

Comment: Do you mean Riemann integrable?

Comment: Riemann integral?

Comment: integrability defined in term of lower and upper sums, i.e. infimums and supremums

Comment: Hint: If you change $f$ at finitely many places, its supremum of lower sums and its infimum of upper sums do not change.

Comment: Compare your function with the [Thomae's function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thomae%27s_function) and see whether you can modify a proof of its integrability (you can find those on MSE or somewhere else)

Comment: I agree with bjorn93.  If you understand the proof that Thomae's function is integrable, then you can imitate it in your case.  (And conversely.)

Answer (score 0):

Consider $g(x) = 1-f(x)$, so it suffices to solve
$$
\int_{[0,1]}f(x) dx = 1 - \int_{[0,1]} g(x) dx
$$
where $g(x)$ is almost the Thomae's function as comments mentioned, and you can refer to [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1427612/integrability-of-thomaes-function-on-0-1) for a proof, you just need to modify a little.

Comment: shouldn't the 1st statement be "the upper sum of $f$ is 1?

Comment: well I am dumb, sorry :( nevertheless the second one should be correct.