# If a sequence $f_n$ converges uniformly to $f$, then the Riemann integral $\lim_{n\to\infty}\int f_n=\int f$ - is my proof correct?

Tags: real-analysis, solution-verification, uniform-convergence, riemann-integration, uniform-continuity

> If $(f_n)_{n=1}^\infty$ is a sequence of Riemann integrable functions defined on a compact interval $I$ which uniformly converges with limit $f$, then $f$ is Riemann integrable and:$$\int_If=\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_If_n$$

Uniform convergence of the sequence means that for any $\varepsilon\gt0$, $\exists N:\forall n\gt N,\forall x,|f_n(x)-f(x)|\lt\varepsilon$.

$$0\le\left|\int_If_n-f\right|\lt\int_I|f_n-f|\lt\varepsilon L$$

Where $n$ is such that $|f_n-f|\lt\varepsilon$ (such $n$ must exist by assumption) and $L$ is the range of the compact interval, which is finite. As for any $\varepsilon\gt0$, $n$ exists (but increases as $\varepsilon$ decreases), we know $n\to\infty\implies\varepsilon\to0$. Therefore:

$$0\le\lim_{n\to\infty}\left|\int_If_n-f\right|\lt\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_I|f_n-f|\lt\lim_{n\to\infty}\varepsilon L=0\\\therefore0\le\lim_{n\to\infty}\left|\int_If_n-f\right|\lt0\\\therefore\lim_{n\to\infty}\left|\int_If_n-f\right|=0\implies\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_If_n=f$$

I strongly suspect that my proof is incorrect, since I never used the fact $I$ was compact, only that it was finite, and I also have never studied real analysis to any great degree so I'm probably lacking some rigour here. Can anyone verify or make corrections to my proof?

P.S I know (EDIT: I *thought* I knew!) $I$ being compact and $f_n$ being integrable over $I$ implies $f_n$ is uniformly continuous for all $n$, but didn't know how to use that fact.

Comment: $f_n$ being integrable does not implies that it is uniformly continuous. $f_n$ might not be even continuous.

Comment: @ArcticChar Musn't $f_n$ be piecewise continuous (over a compact interval) therefore uniformly continuous?

Comment: [Thomae function is Riemann integrable](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1427612/integrability-of-thomaes-function-on-0-1), but is not piecewise continuous.

Comment: @ArcticChar Ok, thank you. I did not see that answer show that $f$ was Riemann integrable - they only did a very similar proof to mine

Comment: Well, there are two answers there....

Comment: @ArcticChar Thank you for coming back to help some more - I read through both answers on the post you linked and now understand it. Thanks!

Comment: If you find the post there answered your question, please consider voting to close it a duplicate.

Comment: @ArcticChar Excuse me - I was on my phone - the vote to close wasn’t visible to me. It is now closed as a duplicate I think